# AWS Lambda Provisioning Business Logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS Lambda, there is no need of provisioning done by us. But I was wondering how AWS Lambda might be provisioning machines to run for the requests. Is it creating a EC2 server for each request and execute the request and then kill the server? Or it keeps some EC2 servers always on to serve the request by executing the lambda function? If its doing the former point, then I am wondering it would also affect performance of AWS Lambda to serve the request. Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas run inside of a [docker-like container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html), on EC2 servers ([using Firecracker](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/)) that are highly, highly optimized. AWS has thousands of servers running full time to serve all of the Lambda functions that are running.

A cold start Lambda (one that's never been run before) starts up in a few seconds, depending on how big it is. An EC2 server takes 30+ seconds to startup. If it had to startup an EC2 server, you'd never be able to use a Lambda through API gateway (because API Gateway has a 30 second timeout). But obviously you can.

If you want your Lambdas to startup super duper fast (100ms), use [Provisioned Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html).

Comment: They [don't](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/) run inside of Docker containers. And I've not seen any indication that AWS Lambda use ECS at all.

Comment: @jarmod I've seen AWS employees comment in the past that Lambda uses containers, and the link you posted, as well as [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/), mention containers several times. Plus the fact that they opened up Lambda to allow you to [deploy your own containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) strongly indicates that Lambda uses containers on the backend. I agree that Lambda probably doesn't use ECS, but actually the same underlying technology that Fargate uses.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, containerized but specifically not Docker. I should have been clearer.

Comment: OK. Fixed it. Better?

Comment: Also, for the record, I was at a 400 level AWS re-invent talk many years ago where the speaker accidentally said that they were docker containers, and then asked politely that we all un-hear what he just said and said "just containers". They were Docker containers at some point. I guess it's morphed/been optimized since then.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is known to reuse the resources. It will not create an EC2 server for each request so that will not be a performance concern

But you should note that the disk space provided for your function sometimes not cleanup properly. [As some users reported](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=209428)

You can read more on the execution life cycle of Lambda here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html